# MVC Razor Multi cell select datagrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datagridview

I'm busy re-doing a winforms app to webforms using mvc razor, and need to mimic the below behaviour using mvc.

[image]

Basically, a report needs to be generated based on selected cells in any column/row.

Any idea's on the best way to do it?

Comment: it's clien-side problem and it looks like you need to write some amount of js code to solve it

Comment: That was the thinking behind it as well, but thought there must be a simpler way with the clever mvc tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add vertical and horizontal checkboxes to select certain cells.

Tested with IEnumerable using ViewBags and works perfect for me.

```html
<table class="table-bordered" cellpadding="4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Columns)
            {
                <th>@Html.CheckBox("col", false) Column Header</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var rowData in ViewBag.RowData)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("row", false) Row Header</td>
                @foreach (var rowCount in ViewBag.Rows)
                {
                    <th>val</th>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This would still require you to add the colouring using js on the selected cells, but programmatically, you can populate the grid dynamically and using the results from the model. PS! replace viewbag with your model (used viewbag for testing)